# Java Jersery: How to handle regular expression within REST URL

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I have implemented a rest Query as shown below:

```
@Path("list")
@GET
public List<Todo> getTodos(@Context UriInfo uriInfo){
  MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
  List<String> parameterList = queryParameters.get(assignee.name);   //Output -> name1,name2 parameterList --  size -1
  String parameter = queryParameters.getFirst(assignee.name); //Output -> name1,name2
  .
  .
  .
}
```

How do I handle when regular expressions are passed

Eg:

Case1:

```
http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?title*=Sam*
```

Case2:

```
http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?title.regexSam*
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use post, put the regular expression in json and send to api.
Because it may be escaped, if you use get.

Comment: The requirement is its a get API, and it needs to fetch all the records matching the conditions.

Comment: ok. you can use `URLEncoder.encode(expression,"utf-8")` to make sure not be escaped.